# Optimising fullcalendar with meteor for large data

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using an auto-run block where I re-execute the same mongo with a few session variables ! loop over those doc , construct an array of events then I call the addEventSource and refetchResources function which are pretty expensive computationally !  the fullcalendar becomes slow the more data ! on every action the auto-run block is rerun !  what in your in your opinion can be done to speed things up ? I thought about only re-rendering the delta elements but this doesn't cover the deletion and update .

```
   calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    schedulerLicenseKey: Meteor.settings.public.fullCalendarLicenseKey,
    now: new Date(),
    editable: true, // enable draggable events
    droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
    aspectRatio: 1.8,
    timezone:'local',
    disableDragging: true,
    displayEventTime: false,
    selectable:true,
    allDaySlot:true,
    slotDuration:'24:00',
    lazyFetching:true,
    resourceLabelText: 'Employees',
    nextDayThreshold:"12:00",
    resources: function(callback) {
      var tmp_obj = { usersSorting : { } };
      tmp_obj.usersSorting["indexByLocation."+Session.get("locationId")] = 1;
      var users = [];
      var data = Meteor.users.find({
        $or:[
          {"profile.showInScheduler":{$exists:false}},
          {"profile.showInScheduler":true}
        ],
        assignedTo:{$in:[Session.get("locationId")]},
        'locations._id':Session.get("locationId"),
        "profile.companyId":Session.get("companyId")
      },{sort : tmp_obj.usersSorting});

      var arr = data.map(function(c) {
        var employeeType = c.userSettings.employeeType;
        var type = EmployeeType.findOne({_id:employeeType});
        var img = Images.findOne({_id: c.picture});
        var imgUrl = img ? img.url() : "/images/default-avatar.png";
        c.name = c.name || "";

        var totalHoursAllLocation = 0;
        var totalHoursCurrentLocation = 0;
        return {
          id: c._id,
          title: "t",
          width:"2px"
        };
      });
      callback(arr);
    },
    drop: function(date, jsEvent, ui, resourceId) {
    },
    eventResize: function( event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view )  {
    },
    dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view,res,res2) {

    },
    eventClick: function ( event, jsEvent, view )  {
    }
  }).data().fullCalendar;


  /********************* reactive calendar *****************/
  this.autorun(function() {


  if(Session.get("activeUsers")) {
    schedulerSubs = Meteor.subscribe("SchedulesByLocation", Session.get("companyId"), Session.get("locationId"), Session.get("activeUsers"), moment(Session.get("currentDate")).startOf('week').toDate(), moment(Session.get("currentDate")).startOf('week').add(2, "weeks").endOf('isoweek').add(1,"days").toDate());
  }

    const company = Companies.findOne({_id: Session.get("companyId")});
    Session.set("loading", true);
    let events = [];
    let usersInLocation = Meteor.users.find({
      assignedTo: {$in: [Session.get("locationId")]},
      'locations._id': Session.get("locationId"),
      "profile.companyId": Session.get("companyId")
    }).fetch();
    let userIds = _.map(usersInLocation, "_id");
    userIds.push("temp" + Session.get("companyId") + Session.get("locationId"));
    Session.set("activeUsers",userIds);
    if(schedulerSubs && schedulerSubs.ready()) {
      var data;

    SchedulerEvts = Schedules.find({
      uid: {$in: userIds},
      locationId: Session.get("locationId"),
      companyId: Session.get("companyId"),
      start: {$gte: moment(Session.get("currentDate")).startOf('week').toDate()},
      end: {$lte: moment(Session.get("currentDate")).add(2, "week").endOf('isoweek').toDate()}
    }).fetch();

      SchedulerEvts.forEach(function (evt) {
        var event = null;
        var color = "";
        var oloc = "";
        var attendance = null;
        var locationName = "";
        var id = evt._id;


      event = {
        id:id,
        type : evt.type,
        title: evt.name,
        start: evt.start,
        end: evt.end,
        color:color,
        resourceId: evt.uid,
        locationName:locationName,

      };

        events.push(event);
      });


      if (calendar) {
        calendar.removeEvents();
        calendar.addEventSource(events);
        calendar.refetchResources();
      }
    }
```

Comment: please show the offending code, it's hard to grasp the exact flow of control and data just by a description.

Comment: i just posted the code!

Comment: a better way to tell fullCalendar what events to use is directly via the "events" property. Either as a feed compliant with the requirements (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/) or an array that lets you customise the ajax call and/or returned data (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/). Is there any reason you didn't do it like this?

Comment: I don't know Meteor and I don't know what triggers "autorun", so maybe that gives some sort of reason for doing it differently? Should be more efficient to do it the "official" way than pushing to an array and then running addEventSource, plus fullCalendar will automatically only fetch what's needed for the current display (assuming the server filters the feed appropriately). And if you want to trigger a fetch outside the normal "change view/date" trigger, you just run the "refetchEvents" method. Lastly why do you need to refetch the resources after this operation?